# How do you remove items from an ASP.NET Drop Down List without knowing anything about contents

Tags: asp.net

I have a drop down list in ASP.NET.

I want to remove every item from this list apart from the first one.

I see there is a Remove methond on items but it dosn't seeem to meet my needs.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could grab the first element and store it in a local variable, then remove all items (Clear method) and finally add the first element again.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the code for the clear method:

```
var listItem = DropDownList.Items[0];

DropDownList.Items.Clear();


DropDownList.Items.Add(listItem);
```

Answer (score 6):

you could loop through the items and remove them all apart from the first

```
int count = DropDownList.Items.Count - 1;
for (int i = count; i > 0; i--)
    DropDownList.Items.RemoveAt(i);
```

[Stefan's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187946/how-do-you-remove-items-from-an-asp-net-drop-down-list-without-knowing-anything-a/1187957#1187957) is going to be much more performant for a larger number of items, but I thought I'd offer up another solution

Answer (score -1):

here is the simple code for adding item in javascript..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AddItem(Text,Value)
{
    // Create an Option object for adding item to dropdownlist       
    var opt = document.createElement("option");

    // Add an Option object to Drop Down/List Box
    document.getElementById("DropDownList").options.add(opt);
    // Assign text and value to Option object
    opt.text = Text;
    opt.value = Value;

}<script />
```

referred from :
http://thedotnetdeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-add-remove-items-in-dropdown.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.